# PHP Showing A Sum Result of a Column Value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to show a sum result of a column name `ref_com` from `wp_users` table in my wordpress site.For this I have written following code but it is showing an `Array` text as output value.What's wrong I am doing? Below is my code

```
<?php 
     $result=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT sum(ref_com) as result FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."users WHERE referredby = '$username'");  
     echo $result; 
?>
```

Comment: You have an sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: how can i  avoid this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_results` function by default returns array of row objects. So if you just directly do `echo $result` it will print `Array`. Try to do `echo $result[0]->result` instead.

Answer (score 1):

loop through the array and echo the result

```
foreach($result as $r){

 echo $r->result;

}
```